# Smooth Mouse Wheel Scroll - Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, parallax, mousewheel, gsap

I'm looking for a vanilla javascript solution (or vanilla Library) to achieve a **Smooth Mouse Wheel Scroll**

[Something like this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLhs0fkn/1/)
But with vanilla JS

I don't want the ease click to #someLink.

Just focus on the Scroll using the mouse wheel to emulate the trackpad effect

This is a [code](http://bassta.bg/2013/05/smooth-page-scrolling-with-tweenmax/) using TweenMax and ScrollToPlugin, but still trying to pass to vanilla :S

```
var $window = $(window);
var scrollTime = 1.2;
var scrollDistance = 170;

window.addEventListener("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){

    event.preventDefault(); 

    var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 || -event.originalEvent.detail/3;
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta*scrollDistance);

    TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
        scrollTo : { y: finalScroll, autoKill:true },
            ease: Power1.easeOut,
            overwrite: 5                            
        });

});
```

Comment: i don't know what the fiddle is supposed to accomplish, but seems a little broken, when i focus on the panel to test mouse wheel by clicking between 2 blue squares, scroll is sometimes blocked..

Comment: Hello, the point is not to click, just scroll, the squares are just visual to see the effect

Comment: I get it, it's because scroll is disabled when you hover a blue square, i don't know if it was intended, but it feels weird to use

Comment: weird, in my laptop is doesn't disable when hover